# c# automatizar login

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-forms, navegador-web

Quiero automatizar el login en un Windows Forms, estoy usando un componente CefSharp para cargar el navegador en un formulario Windows Forms en c# y le estoy mandando parametros JavaScript.

Le mando parametro Usuario desde c# y en el navegador me lo pone correctamente y hago lo mismo con el password, el problema viene cuando mando a llamar o doy click en el boton para hacer el login y el formulario me lo detecta como si los campos usuarios y password los tuviera vacios (usuario requerido).

Hay alguna manera de que me detecte que no esta vacio realmente?

el script que mando es el siguiente:

```html
document.getElementById('user').value = 'usuario';document.getElementById('pass').value = 'usuario';
```

Comment: debes implementar el evento WebNav_DocumentCompleted, y dentro de este setea los datos para luego llamar al botón o dar click

Comment: @jtaborga Ese evento no lo tiene el ChromiumBrowser del CefSharp, igualmente lo puse en uno evento que dice FrameLoadEnd e igual no funciona, si setea los datos y todo pero al momento de dar clic al button los detecta como vacios por alguna validacion yo creo (no soy el autor de la pagina).

Comment: Utiliza el componente WebNavigator de c#, el evento se llama DocumentCompleted

Comment: @jtaborga la pagina que quiero cargar no la soporta el WebNagivator por eso cambie al componente de CefSharp, trae codigo react y no me carga en WebNavigator.

Comment: voy a elaborar un ejemplo te escribiré en respuestas cuando lo tenga listo